# Get URL in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am very new to python and I am looking to scrape following website:[Link](http://planning.hackney.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/generalsearch.aspx)

I think that Selenium might be the right tool and I started to write following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

path='http://planning.hackney.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/generalsearch.aspx'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(path)

elem = browser.find_element_by_id('txtPostCode')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("E9 7JP")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print (browser.current_url)
```

So far so good, it works. However, the return value of `browser.current_url` is not quite what is displayed in the url bar of my browser. I mean the the return value of the script is:

`//planning.hackney.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/generalsearch.aspx`

however the url in the browser is showing me this one here:

`//planning.hackney.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/Generic/StdResults.aspx?PT=Planning%20Applications%20On-Line&SC=Postcode%20is%20E9%207JP&FT=Planning%20Application%20Search%20Results&XMLSIDE=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/Hackney/Menus/PL.xml&XSLTemplate=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/Hackney/xslt/PL/PLResults.xslt&PS=10&XMLLoc=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/Generic/XMLtemp/j5jzxiwxklgslnam4qffypw5/052dd052-3993-4f10-83aa-dd0c6c326676.xml`

Now I wonder how to get hold of this adress?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you add your Python version, python-selenium version, firefoxdriver version and firefox version to the post? I could not reproduce your issue using python3, python-selenium 2.53, firefoxdriver 2.53 and Firefox 45.9.0. Running your scripts gives me longer URL, just like you expected.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my python version is 3.6.1, selenium is 3.4.0, Firefox is 53, i have no idea how to figure out the version of the Firefox driver, but it's the newest one. l installed selenium just a few days ago..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you made any other request in between checking your script returned URL and the URL shown by the browser. The request URL sent post the `Keys.RETURN` adds a session identifier with the URL, which might be the reason why you are getting different URL.

I have this script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chromepath='chrome_driver_path' //change this to your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath)
```

`driver.get('http://planning.hackney.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/generalsearch.aspx')`

```
print(driver.current_url)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('txtPostCode')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("E9 7JP")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print (driver.current_url)

driver.quit()
```

Keypress code has been copied from your code itself. I get an identical URL from both the browser and the script

Script gives me this URL - [Link](http://planning.hackney.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/Generic/StdResults.aspx?PT=Planning%20Applications%20On-Line&SC=Postcode%20is%20E9%207JP&FT=Planning%20Application%20Search%20Results&XMLSIDE=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/Hackney/Menus/PL.xml&XSLTemplate=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/Hackney/xslt/PL/PLResults.xslt&PS=10&XMLLoc=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/Generic/XMLtemp/12cu0uxljoqxlks400ugehsi/32e94f87-5fd6-40bf-b362-6def929013a8.xml)
Browser gives me this same URL - [Copied Manually](http://planning.hackney.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/Generic/StdResults.aspx?PT=Planning%20Applications%20On-Line&SC=Postcode%20is%20E9%207JP&FT=Planning%20Application%20Search%20Results&XMLSIDE=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/Hackney/Menus/PL.xml&XSLTemplate=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/Hackney/xslt/PL/PLResults.xslt&PS=10&XMLLoc=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/Generic/XMLtemp/12cu0uxljoqxlks400ugehsi/32e94f87-5fd6-40bf-b362-6def929013a8.xml)

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot! it works! the same code give me different results depending on the driver i am using...   meaning that the Firefox driver gives me the short address, the chrome driver the long one and the one i need...